# The preview in my visual studio editor is not the same as the outcome in the web page

Tags: github, synchronization

The preview in my visual studio editor is not the same as the outcome in the web page when I upload the content (html and css). I compare them side by side. Help?

I uploaded the content into a Github repository.

I wrote some html and css code and publish it into a repository.

I was hoping for the content to look the same in both parts, the local preview and the web but they are different so I cannot assess the problem. I already know that there is a latency of a couple minutes after I synchronize the modifications, but nevertheless longer than that, both views look different.